# Does PostgreSQL have a way to return month names in the local name, not english?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, datetime

I need to return month names from queries. I think that returning 1 for january, 2 for february and processing that on the front-end is not good. I need to return month names in portuguese Janeiro, Fevereiro and etc. PosgreSQL provides a way to return months in the local format or should I create a table? That's just curiosity, I am completely ok in creating table with dozen of rows manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the `TM` prefix](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) to return the days and months names in the language of locale [`lc_time`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-LC-TIME):

```
select to_char(current_date, 'dd TMMonth')
```

`lc_time` is inherited from the environment if not otherwise set. You can display its current value with command `show lc_time`.